# gunicorn flask server returns 404 for existing endpoint

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I am refactoring my working flask server app (a bot) to use gunicorn to avail of its multi-worker model and other benefits for WSGI. I am able to launch gunicorn server listening on default (5000) port. Somehow when do GET for `/` endpoint it returns 404. And `/` endpoint exists and returns 'Hello'

Erro seen on client side

```
curl http://localhost:5000/
404
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again
```

File Organization

```
├── wsgi.py
├── bot.py
```

Server launched using gunicorn

```
(venv) % gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 bot:app 
[2020-09-05 14:52:49 -0700] [45263] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-05 14:52:49 -0700] [45263] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (45263)
[2020-09-05 14:52:49 -0700] [45263] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-05 14:52:49 -0700] [45266] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45266
```

wsgi.py

```
from bot import launch_bot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    launch_ria_bot()
```

bot.py

```
import logging
import os

from flask import Flask

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)

def launch_ria_bot():

    @app.before_first_request
    def init_bot():
        log.info(os.getcwd())
        

    @app.route('/')
    def bot_home():
        return 'Hello!'

    @app.route('/bot/query', methods=["GET"])
    def query():
        # process_query()
        return response, 200

    app.run()
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Looks straight forwards to me.
P.S. I have seen some posts on StackOverflow that say using the name `app` for file or module can be colliding. Hence I completely avoided using that name for file/module.

Comment: That's an unusual way to structure things. What are you pointing gunicorn at? If it's bot.py, then `launch_ria_bot` won't run, and you'll have no routes.

Comment: @Dave W. Smith what would be the right way to structure it? What sall I point it to then?

Answer (score 0):

That code has one issue that hiding a second issue.

First, since gunicorn is being pointed at `bot:app`, `launch_ria_bot()` never runs, so no routes are added. wsgi.py never gets involved, but if it did, you'd encounter the second problem: `uwsgi` supplies the equivalent of `app.run()`.

The simplest way forward is to in-line `launch_ria_bot()`, leaving

```
...
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request
def init_bot():
   ...

@app.route('/')
def bot_home():
   ...

@app.route('/bot/query', methods=["GET"])
def query():
   ...
```

and then either remove the `app.run()`, since `uwsgi` will do that for you, or rewrite it as

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

so that `python bot.py` will start the app under the development server.